# Sphinx center graphviz directive

Tags: graphviz, python-sphinx

I'm using the graphviz directive in Sphinx. I have tried using the 'center' directive, though it appears one directive cannot apply to another, or I'm doing it wrong:

```
.. centered::
.. graphviz::
```

Or

```
.. graphviz::
    :align: center
```

How do I make the outputted graph centered on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well, and did some research.

As of version 1.4.4 this is not available; however, [a change has been merged to allow this](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/commit/1d17475a08c70289d4ca575090d0ee3854a53c7b).

I assume it will be available with the next minor release (1.5).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem and I solve this by:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz install section indicates you have to install graphviz package with `pip install graphviz` in your project ?